# Research plan without a specific goal?

Tags: research-process, university, application

In order to apply for studying abroad (writing my M.Sc. thesis) I need to write a research plan. However, I only know the approximate research field, e.g. "program analysis for concurrent software", but I was not assigned an actual topic or specific goal yet.

How am I supposed to write a research plan without knowing any more details? I'm completely inexperienced regarding such paperwork (never had to do it before), therefore I relied on templates and guides I found on the internet, but they all assume you already know a specific goal.

What am I supposed to write in this case? Is there some outline I can use as an orientation?

Comment: what did your supervisor say? What do the research plans from previous students on your course look like?

Comment: I don't have one yet, I'm basically applying to get one. Since this is no course per se, there are no "previous" students like in a regular course. There might be previously supervised students but I don't have access to their applications nor do I know them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had an experience with along these lines from the other side recently, working with a student to write a plan for the research that he would be doing under me during a three-month visit.  We had to be ultra-specific in order to meet visa requirements, but the project had a lot of uncertainties in it.
In fact, however, the challenge of writing a specific research statement was quite useful for making sure we thought a bit more in advance and were able to get a fast start once my student arrived.

I would recommend getting in touch with the person that you are expected be working with abroad, and set up a time to talk (Skype, Gchat, whatever) about some more specific goals.  Some good examples of starting points for a discussion:

- Are there particular types of analysis technique that are likely to be used?
- Are there particular pieces of software that are likely to be good test cases?
- What is the goal? Do you want to find security issues, bugs, inefficiencies, usability, portability, robustness, something else?  Or are you just trying to exercise the scalability of the techniques?
- What are some intermediate checkpoints that you can use to know if you are making progress towards your thesis?  What should be done in 1 month? 3 months? 6 months?

It's OK if the answers change while you're there.  Everybody understands that research is research and that things may change.  But going in with a concrete plan will help a lot in making good use of your time, in understanding whether something *has* changed, and if so what you want to do about it.

And if the potential supervisor abroad can't make time for a meeting with you?  Then maybe you should rethink whether this would be the right place to go...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'd like to add my experience, since I already handed my plan in: I suspected the main focus to be whether I am familiar with the research field and/or if I'm capable of digging into it, therefore focused heavily on this part, with success.

Comment: Glad to hear it, and I hope your study abroad goes well!